# How to remove all rows and columns entirely with zeros in panda Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, drop

i want all rows and columns filled with zeros entirely need to be removed.

but it is returning only this.

```
      Box_deatils    1    5
0           1  0.0  0.0
1           2  1.0  0.0
2           3  1.0  0.0
3           4  0.0  0.0
4           5  0.0  0.0
5           6  0.0  1.0
  Box_deatils    1    5
0           1  0.0  0.0
1           2  1.0  0.0
2           3  1.0  0.0
3           4  0.0  0.0
4           5  0.0  0.0
5           6  0.0  1.0
```

row removal is not happening only column is happening

Please help to find whats wrong below.

```
Soln=[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
    
    result=pd.DataFrame(Soln)

Final_result=result.loc[:,(result !=0).any(axis=0)]

print(Final_result)

Final_result=Final_result.loc[(Final_result !=0).any(axis=1)]

print(Final_result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, row *filled with zeros* is actually a row where
all "numeric-named" columns (in your case *1* and *5*) have only zeros
(the value in *Box_deatils* (or *Box_details*) column doesn't matter).

To do it, you can run:

```
df.drop(df.index[df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(0).all(axis=1)], inplace=True)
```

and *df* now contains:

```
   Box_deatils    1    5
1            2  1.0  0.0
2            3  1.0  0.0
5            6  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful with `.loc` an`.iloc` , they are **not the same thing**, more info here: [loc and iloc in Pandas](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/loc-iloc-pandas/)

I would use either "loc/iloc" approach or the `.where` approach, which I personally find easier:

```
df= df.where((df['column1'] != 0) & (df['column2'] != 0))
```

this worked for me in many cases.

Comment: `&`, not `and`. Also, this doesn't explain what is actually wrong with OP's code

Comment: @Mad Physicist : Thanks for the correction. I wanted to post a working solution, easier for a novice, and letting him better read info about loc/iloc

Comment: The actual question is "Please help to find whats wrong below.", Not "please post a working solution"

Comment: Also, please don't post comments into your answer. While I very much appreciate the attribution, all you really need to do is just fix the error.